# Attemp to read property on array error - PHP REST service

Tags: php, sql, database, rest

So im working on a REST service with php righ now. Later its gonna be consumed with anther page, but right now im testing to make sure i can use CRUD properly with what I've made and the GET is working, and also GET with ID and so on, but when I use the "POST" it does add to the database but it doesnt send any values with it so it creates blank values.

The structuring of the code is the way we suppose to do it at this stage of the education.

Im getting the following error: (the last message line translates to "experience created")

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Attempt to read property "workplace" on array in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\webbutveckling3\projektrest\experience.php</b> on line <b>67</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Attempt to read property "title" on array in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\webbutveckling3\projektrest\experience.php</b> on line <b>68</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Attempt to read property "startdate" on array in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\webbutveckling3\projektrest\experience.php</b> on line <b>69</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Attempt to read property "enddate" on array in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\webbutveckling3\projektrest\experience.php</b> on line <b>70</b><br />
{"Message":"Erfarehet har skapats"}
```

When I look at teachers example I cant see a differnce (obviously there is one..)
I cant figure out why I get this error and why the values i do in the Advanced rest client isnt sending and giving this error.

Im adding a [link to picture](https://gyazo.com/f59dc747f575c2f0e57df7f5421bb013) of my Rest client attempt too.

Edit with vardump in POST case:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (4) {
    ["workplace"]=>
    string(6) "Test23"
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Test 33"
    ["startdate"]=>
    int(20210309)
    ["enddate"]=>
    int(20210310)
  }
}
```

This is my experience.php file:

```
    <?php 
    
    
    
    //* REST-webbtjänst för experience, kopplas till klass Database.php och klass Experience.php
    require 'classes/Database.php';
    require 'classes/Experience.php';
    
    
    //* Headers för tillgänglighet från alla domäner:
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    
    //* Kolla om id är satt med if-sats:
        if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
        }
    
    //* Databas-anrop via klassen Database:
    
    $db = new Database();
    
    //Variabel för ny erfarenhet och  skicka med db samt anropsmetod
    $experience = new Experience($db);
    
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    
    //* Switch sats med olika metoder som kallar för klassfunktioner från Experience.php
    
    switch($method) {
        
        // GET metod utläsning av ett värde med id eller hela listan
    
        //* Case 1
    
        case 'GET':
            //Om id är valt
            if(isset($id)) {
                $result = $experience->readExperience($id);
            } else { //Om id ej är valt
                $result = $experience->readExperiences();
            }
    
            // Om värdet är större än 0
            if(sizeof($result) > 0) {
                http_response_code(200); // Kod för ok
            } else {
                http_response_code(404); //Kod för not found
                $result = array("Message" => "Inga tidigare erfarenheter hittades");
            }   
    
            //Avsluta case 1
            break;
    
            // POST metod för skapa ny erfarenhet
    
            //* Case 2
    
        case 'POST':
            
            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    
            //variabler
            $experience->workplace = $data->workplace;
            $experience->title = $data->title;
            $experience->startdate = $data->startdate;
            $experience->enddate = $data->enddate;
    
            if($experience->createExperience()) {
                http_response_code(201); // Kod för ok
                //Meddelande om skapad erfarehet
                $result = array("Message" => "Erfarehet har skapats");
            } else {
                http_response_code(503); // Kod för Service unavailable
                $result = array("Message" => "kunde ej skapa erfarenhet");
            }
            //Avsluta case 2
            break;
    
            //PUT metod för att uppdatera en erfarenhet
    
            //* Case 3
    
            case 'PUT': {
                //Om inget id är valt
                if(!isset($id)) {
                    http_response_code(510); // Kod för not extended
                    $result = array("Message" => "Inget id är valt");
                } else {
                    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
                    //variabler
                    $experience->workplace = $data->workplace;
                    $experience->title = $data->title;
                    $experience->startdate = $data->startdate;
                    $experience->enddate = $data->enddate;
    
                    if($experience->updateExperience($id)) {
                        http_response_code(200); // Kod för ok
                        $result = array("Message" => "Erfarehet uppdaterad");
                    } else {
                        http_response_code(503); // Kod för Service unavailable
                        $result = array("Message" => "kunde ej uppdatera erfarenhet");
                    }
    
                }
            }
            //Avsluta case 3
            break;
    
            //DELETE metod för att radera en erfarenhet
    
            //* Case 4
    
            case 'DELETE':
                //Om inget id
                if(!isset($id)) {
                    http_response_code(510); // Kod för not extended
                    $result = array("Message" => "Inget id valt");
                } else {
                    if($experience->deleteExperience($id)) {
                        http_response_code(200); // Kod för ok
                        $result = array("Message" => "Erfarehet raderad");
                    } else {
                        http_response_code(503); // Kod för Service unavailable
                        $result = array("Message" => "kunde ej radera erfarenhet");
                    }
                }
                //Avsluta sista case
                break;
    
    
    }
    
    
    
    //* Returnera resultatet via $result i json-format:
        echo json_encode($result);
    
    //* Stäng databas
        $db->close();
    
    
    
    ?>
```

The experience.php class file (I know same name not good practice)

```
<?php


//* Klassfil för att hantera CRUD för experience.php



//* Klass:
class Experience {
    
    //* Databasanslutning:
        public function __construct($db) {
            $this->db = $db->connect();
        }


    //* Klassfunktioner:
        // Dessa kallas från fil för att genomföra CRUD uppgifter mot databasen



    //* Visa en erfarenhet med id: "readExperience"
            public function readExperience($id) {
                $sql= "SELECT * FROM experience WHERE id=$id";
                $result = $this->db->query($sql);
                return mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            }
    

    //* Visa alla erfarenheter: "readExperiences
            public function readExperiences() {   
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM experience ORDER BY startdate ASC"; 
                $result = $this->db->query($sql); 
                return mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
            }


    //* Skapa ny erfarenhet: "createExperience"
            public function createExperience() {    
                $sql = "INSERT INTO experience(workplace, title, startdate, enddate) VALUES ('$this->workplace', '$this->title', '$this->startdate', '$this->enddate')";
                $result = $this->db->query($sql); 
                return $result;  
            } 

            
           

    //* Uppdatera erferenhet: "updateExperience"
            public function updateExperience(int $id) {       
                $sql = "UPDATE experience SET workplace='$this->workplace', title='$this->title', startdate='$this->startdate', enddate='$this->enddate' WHERE id=$id";
                $result = $this->db->query($sql);
                return $result;  
            } 



    //* Radera erfarenhet: "deleteExperience"
            public function deleteExperience(int $id) {
                $sql = "DELETE FROM experience WHERE id=$id";
                $result = $this->db->query($sql);
                return $result;
            }




}





?>
```

If needed here is the Database class too:

```
class Database {

        public $db;

        public function connect() {
            $this->db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
            $this->db->connect_errno > 0 ? die('Fel vid databasanslutning[' . $db->connect_error . ']') : null;
            return $this->db; 
        }


        // Stäng databas
        public function close() {
            $this->db->close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do `var_dump($data);` in your POST case and check what that variable actually contains (I'm assuming that's where the warnings are thrown?)

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: Nothing is adapted yet for security or anything, not even a form or page to handle the service is made

Comment: Added vardump into edited post

Comment: _"Nothing is adapted yet for security"_ - Security should be a part of the design, not an after through. Adding security after can be a cumbersome job and can cause new issues. You might also spend a lot of time fixing issues with code you're just going to rewrite anyway (like your database code).

Comment: It seems like the object you're sending is inside an array so you will need to do: `$data[0]->workplace` and so on.

Comment: Im aware of that, but this task is very specific and about to just learn the method and way you consume the service etc, its literally made with random data to try make it, and use it and wont be part of any bigger project,

Comment: Just remember that passing certain characters (like a single `'`) in any of the values you store would completely break your query. Protecting against injections isn't just about security.

Comment: It's not about adding debug code to the question :D Add it in your code and check what it displays. BTW it is good practice to concentrate and show only part of code which causes  errors (usually can be determined by line number in error message). It would help us to read it and you to find what's wrong. At least you could write line numbers for 67 - 70

Comment: I did add it into the code and that was the ouput i added, sorry there are no lines, dont know how to add it i copied it straight from the editor

Comment: Did you see my comment above? For some reason, you're getting the object in an array. This comes from the client you're using. Either sort the client out so it sends the object directly or access the object with `$data[0]->workplace` and so on in your code.

Comment: Wow that worked! Thanks, I need to figure out why that works tho now :P but thanks!